# Microsoft Band custom tile events in a background task on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, microsoft-band

Will Windows 10 mobile finally support custom tile events in a background task from Microsoft Band?

I know this isn't exactly a programming question, but since MS has made this the "official" place for Band support, I'm forced to battle the politics of stackoverflow.

Comment: I assume you mean "will Windows 10 with the Band SDK allow my application to be notified when certain events occur related to Tiles owned by the application, without requiring the application be running or otherwise connected to the Band".  That's a "what are your future plans" question that generally isn't answered in a public forum.  Your best bet would be to send such questions to msbandsdk@microsoft.com.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thank you Phil.

Comment: Hey Phil, there does not appear to be anyone behind the wheel at that email address. Maybe you could go nudge someone ;)